# AndroidXMapFragment init causes skipped frames

Tags: android, kotlin, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

I'm using the HERE SDK for Android (Premium Edition) v3.18.4.

The following code causes skipped frames (where `mapFragment` is an instance of `com.here.android.mpa.mapping.AndroidXMapFragment`):

```
mapFragment.init { error ->

}
```

As seen in Logcat:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

The strange thing is the issue persists even when wrapping the `init` call in a `Thread`:

```
Thread {
    mapFragment.init { error ->

    }
}.start()
```

So I would assume the `init` implementation is explicitly dispatching some work to the main thread that consumers of the SDK can't work around.

This issue can be reproduced in the [Routing Sample App](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/routing) as well.

**Is there a way for me to work around these skipped frames, or must this be fixed inside the SDK implementation?**

Answer (score 0):

Those warning sometimes happens on low-end devices. After MapEngine initialization is completed, HERE Mobile SDK 3.X does not use UI-thread to render or to perform heavy CPU operations. If you do not see visual hiccups while using MapView, then you can ignore this warning.